Unlock bootloader for Tecno Spark 10C - K15k
I am trying to unlock the bootloader of my Tecno Spark 10c to install custom ROM on it.
C:\Users\Monami and Agnibha\OneDrive\Documents\tecno_root\platform-tools>fastboot flashing unlock
FAILED (remote: 'unknown cmd.')
fastboot: error: Command failed

C:\Users\Monami and Agnibha\OneDrive\Documents\tecno_root\platform-tools>fastboot oem unlock
FAILED (remote: 'Unlock bootloader fail.')
fastboot: error: Command failed

C:\Users\Monami and Agnibha\OneDrive\Documents\tecno_root\platform-tools>fastboot oem unlock-go
FAILED (remote: 'unknown cmd.')
fastboot: error: Command failed

C:\Users\Monami and Agnibha\OneDrive\Documents\tecno_root\platform-tools>fastboot flashing unlock_critical
FAILED (remote: 'Not implement.')
fastboot: error: Command failed

C:\Users\Monami and Agnibha\OneDrive\Documents\tecno_root\platform-tools>

Original screenshot of terminal commands
I have tried everything, and every command, stack forum, and other website doesn't help.
Please help if any experts are there.

The bootloader is manufacturer and/or chipset specific, therefore what you read for other devices may or may not work for your device. Tecno Spark 10C seems to use an Unisoc CPU/chipset - never seen a device before that uses it. Usually a better way is to ask in a vendor specific forum as it exists e.g. on XDA.

Please do not use an imsge for text information

Is my life really worth it?
